# Stacked Bar ordered by Sum of Fill with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

With the following data (an already melted data frame):

```
df1<-structure(list(Speciality = structure(27:32, .Label = c("Addiction Medicine", 
    "Anesthesiology", "Cardiac Electrophysiology", "Cardiology", 
    "Dermatology", "Emergency Medicine", "Family Medicine", "Gastroenterology", 
    "General Surgery", "Hematology & Oncology", "Hospitalist", "Internal Medicine", 
    "Nephrology", "Neurological Surgery", "Neurology", "Obstetrics & Gynecology", 
    "Otolaryngology", "Pain Medicine", "Pathology", "Pediatric Critical Care Medicine", 
    "Pediatric Hematology-Oncology", "Pediatric Pulmonology", "Pediatric Radiology", 
    "Pediatric Surgery", "Pediatrics", "Psychiatry", "Pulmonology", 
    "Radiation Oncology", "Radiology", "Surgical Oncology", "Urology", 
    "Vascular Surgery"), class = "factor"), PhysAge = structure(c(5L, 
    5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("25-34", "35-44", "45-54", "55-64", 
    "65+"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.0035, 0.0058, 0.0089, 0, 0.00512820512820513, 
    0.00512820512820513)), .Names = c("Speciality", "PhysAge", "value"
    ), row.names = 155:160, class = "data.frame")
```

How can I reorder in ggplot based on the sum of values for each `Speciality` in a stacked bar chart. I've found some options where the value is multiple columns, but in this case it's one value column.

Currently plotting by:
`ggplot(df,aes(x=Speciality,y=value,fill=PhysAge))+
 geom_bar(stat="identity")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
set.seed(1)
df <- rbind(
  AgevsPractice.melt, 
  transform(AgevsPractice.melt, PhysAge="1", value=runif(6, 0, 0.01)),
  transform(AgevsPractice.melt, PhysAge="10", value=runif(6, 0, 0.01))
)
ggplot(df,aes(x=reorder(Speciality, value, sum), y=value,fill=PhysAge))+
 geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: Not sure this quite does it. It would end up plotting `PhysAge 1` and `PhysAge 10` when using the fill, which skews the plot. I've also edited a couple things in the sample data to include more levels under `PhysAge`. I was using the tail end of the data, and it was limited to one level. This is the first time I've used `runif()` and I edited it for the larger data set to `runif(160,0,0.01)` would that change the output drastically?

Comment: Hmm I thought you wanted to "reorder in ggplot based on the sum of values for each Speciality in a stacked bar chart". As you didn't provide enough data for a stacked barchart, I created some random (`runif`) dummy data (`df`) just for the sake of demonstration. What problems do you have with your real data?

Comment: My mistake. I just caught that. The answer lay in the `x=reorder(Speciality,value,sum)` Thanks!